# Excel Macro giving error when pasting

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an excel macro which is probably going to end up being quite large, to make things easier I am tackling it a bit at a time.  So far I have....

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Test Macro
'
  'Selects the product_name column by header name
  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("product_name")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "The product_name column was not found."
  Exit Sub
  End If
  Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select

  'Inserts new column to the left of the product_name column
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

  'Re-selects the product_name column
   Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select

  'Copys the contents of the product_name column
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

I want it to do the following....

- Search the spreadsheet for the header name **'product_name'**
- Insert a blank column to the left of the **'product_name'** column
- Copy the contents of the **'product_name'** column
- Paste them into the newly created blank column
- Change the header name in this new column to **'product_name_2'**

Currently it works fine up until the pasting into this newly created column, then i get a

```
'Run-time error '438'; - Object doesn't support this property or method'
```

Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to record the process? The Record macro function usually hints where you go wrong. Try to copy something and pasting it somewhere else while recording and study that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is:

```
Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select
```

This selects from the top of the column down to just above the first blank cell.  The insert shifts this portion of the column right leaving the rest where it is.  When you select again you are likely to get a larger range because you have mixed two columns.  The copy fails because you are then trying to copy values over the top of values.

If that does not make sense, step through your macro with F8 and see what is happening at each step.

When you understand why your current macro does not work, try this:

```
Sub Macro5()

  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Dim ColToBeCopied As Integer

  Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("'product_name")
  If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The product_name column was not found."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ColToBeCopied = rngAddress.Column
  Columns(ColToBeCopied).EntireColumn.Insert
  Columns(ColToBeCopied + 1).Copy Destination:=Columns(ColToBeCopied)

End Sub
```

Note:

1. I did not select anything.
2. I have left the code operating on the active sheet but it is better to use `With Sheets("XXX")` ... `End With`.

**Answer to second question**

The macro recorder is not good at showing how to address individual cells systematically.

```
With Sheets("xxxx")
  .Cells(RowNum,ColNum).Value = "product_name 1"
End With
```

The above uses `With` which I recommend.  Notice the dot in front of Cells.

The one below operates on the active sheet.

```
Cells(RowNum,ColNum).Value = "product_name 1"
```

RowNum must be a number.  ColNum can be a number (say 5) or a letter (say "E").

In your case RowNum is 1 and ColNum is ColToBeCopied and ColToBeCopied + 1.

**P.S.**

I forgot to mention that to find the botton row of a column use:

```
RowLast = Range(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Row
```

That is move up from the bottom not down from the top.

**P.S. 2**

To specify a range using Cells:

```
.Range(.Cells(Top,Left),.Cells(Bottom,Right))
```

The dots must match: all three or none.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining where I was going wrong as well!  I am now struggling with renaming though, as I have two columns named 'product_name'  How could I get one of them to be renamed as product_name_1 and the other as product_name_2?

Comment: I have added the answer to your extra question.  Hope this is clear.  I would be grateful if you accepted my answer.  I must confess I do this for the points, not love of my fellow man or woman.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are trying to copy to, 
but when you want to paste you need to make a selection and then
**ActiveSheet.Paste**
For example:

/your code/
   Selection.Copy

Range("O:O").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid copying / pasting altogether, if you only want to transfer values.

For example, instead of:

```
Range("B1:B100").Copy Destination:=Range("A1")
```

I would use:

```
Range("A1:A100").Value = Range("B1:B100").Value
```

If we were to substitute that into your code, and include some of the comments made by Tony:

```
Sub Macro4()

    Dim colFound  As Integer
    Dim rowLast As Long

    Const rowSearch As Integer = 1

    'Find the product_name column
    colFound = Rows(rowSearch).Find("product_name").Column

    If colFound = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The product_name column was not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Find the last non-empty row
    rowLast = Cells(Rows.Count, colFound).End(xlUp).Row

    'Inserts new column to the left of the product_name column
    Columns(colFound).EntireColumn.Insert

    'Transfer the contents of the product_name column to the newly inserted one
    Range(Cells(rowSearch, colFound), Cells(rowLast, colFound)).Value = _
     Range(Cells(rowSearch, colFound + 1), Cells(rowLast, colFound + 1)).Value

    'Rename the new column
    Cells(rowSearch, colFound).Value = Cells(rowSearch, colFound).Value & "_2"

End Sub
```